# How can I specify column widths in the gt package in R when `cols_width` doesn't work as expected?

Tags: r, gt

## Introduction

I'm working with the `gt` package in R to recreate a table (the goal is to recreate pieces at a time for use in an education setting). I've come across a problem that I can't fix, even after searching and reading the documentation. I'm guessing that there's a small setting/customization in the package that is exactly what I need but I'm missing it.

My table has six columns:

- `measures`: character, this is to be used as a grouping label (with `groupcol_name=`)
- `names`: a vector of empty strings (`""`) which serves as an empty row name column (for `rowname_col=`)
- `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`: all columns with the actual data

I've done a lot of work getting small details right (such as borders, colors, and footnotes), many of which I've removed here for simplicity's sake.

Here's the original draft of the table without my trying what I want to do:

```r
test %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "names", groupname_col = "measure") %>%
  cols_align(align = "left", columns = 1) %>% 
  cols_align(align = "center", columns = 2:6) %>% 
  gt_highlight_cols(A, 
                    fill =c("#81A26B"), 
                    font_color = "#ffffff", 
                    font_weight = "bold") %>%
  gt_highlight_cols(B, 
                    fill = c("#86AEBA"), 
                    font_color = "#ffffff", 
                    font_weight = "bold") %>%
  gt_highlight_cols(C, 
                    fill = c("#CBC361"), 
                    font_color = "#ffffff", 
                    font_weight = "bold") %>%
  gt_highlight_cols(D, 
                    fill = c("#D77085"), 
                    font_color = "#ffffff", 
                    font_weight = "bold")
```

which gives:
table without problem:
[image: table without problem]

## What I'm Looking For

I want

1. The group name to be a column (which I will do below with `row_group.as_column = TRUE`)
2. The `names` (empty) column to be as small as possible
3. The `A`-`D` columns to be equal width
4. The `measures` (group name) column to not be too wide but probably wider than the others

## What I've Done

### Adding Row Group as Column

Here's what I get when I add the `row_group.as_column`:

```r
same_code_as_above %>%
  tab_options(
    row_group.as_column = TRUE
  )
```

which gives:
table with row groups as a column:
[image: table with row groups as a column]

This looks nice so far. But I don't need the row group column to be so wide and I'd like to see if I can force the `A`-`D` columns to be the same width, always.

### Messing With `cols_width`

I have to be misunderstanding this function.

- `cols_width(measure ~ px(1000))` changes nothing about the table (set to 1000 to demonstrate extremeness, no other value works either)
- `cols_width(names ~ px(100))` changes the `measure` column (group name) and NOT the row name column to which `names` is actually tied to
- cols_width(A ~ px(100)) changes the `names` column (rather than the column titled `A`)
- And so on...
- cols_width(D ~ px(100)) changes the `C` column (not `D`) and I have no way to access the `D` column to change its width
- Accessing these columns by their index number does not work as well
- Making adjustments and using `everything()` or `c(A, B, C, D)` still does not get the `D` column and often makes the table too squished that the `D` column disappears

For example, I'll attach the image for

```r
same_code_as_above %>%
  cols_width(D ~ px(1000)) %>%
  tab_options(
    row_group.as_column = TRUE
  )
```

which is:
table with extra wide C column instead of D:
[image: table with extra wide C column instead of D]

After this long explanation I guess I need help trying to get my widths to work. Can I specify different widths for the group column, row name column, and the body columns? How can I access the last column? Please let me know if I can supply anything else.

I'd also like to change the row height of just some rows (not all) but I suppose that's a different question.

Comment: This looks a bug which was already reported on the GH page. See [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1253).

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Can't believe I missed that! Guess I'll wait for a bug fix.